# while start the bro the error is coming "error occurred while trying to send mail: send-mail: SENDMAIL-NOTFOUND not found"

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, bro

I've installed the Bro IDS but when I try to start the service an error is coming that :

```
Error: error occurred while trying to send mail: send-mail: SENDMAIL-NOTFOUND not found
starting ...
starting bro ...
bro terminated immediately after starting; check output with "diag"
```

I've already used `broctl install` and `broctl update` but still got the same error.

Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the configuration file i.e. node.cfg under /nsm/bro/etc and change the default interface eth0 with my system interface.

now bro has started

Answer (score 0):

Bro can run without sendmail present but you may have been hit by a [bug](https://bro-tracker.atlassian.net/browse/BIT-1548) in Bro where it failed to include the Sendmail location in the config files. Whilst it says the bug was supposed to be fixed I've also seen the problem in Bro-2.5. So an easy fix is to do as suggested in the bug report and add the `SendMail = /usr/sbin/sendmail` to `/usr/local/bro/etc/broctl.cfg` and then rerun the deployment command:

```
sudo /usr/local/bro/bin/broctl deploy
```